# OrientDB javascript function stuck when creating indexes

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

function:

```
//name: CD_CreateSubClassIndexes
//params: 
//idempotence: false
//code: 

var codeUnitClasses = db.query("select from (select name from (SELECT expand(classes) FROM #0:1) where superClass = 'CodeUnit') order by name asc");

logger("starting CodeUnit index creation",'info');

for(var i=0; i<codeUnitClasses.length; i++){
  var className = codeUnitClasses[i].field("name");
  logger("starting CodeUnit index creation for class : " + className,'info');
  db.command("CREATE INDEX "+className+".binName ON "+className+" (binName) NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX");
  db.command("CREATE INDEX "+className+".isExcluded ON "+className+" (isExcluded) NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX");
  db.command("CREATE INDEX "+className+".module ON "+className+" (module) NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX");
  db.command("CREATE INDEX "+className+".module_binName ON "+className+" (module,binName) NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX");
  db.command("CREATE INDEX "+className+".module_name_new ON "+className+" (module, name) NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX");
  db.command("CREATE INDEX "+className+".module_type ON "+className+" (module,type) NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX");
  db.command("CREATE INDEX "+className+".name ON "+className+" (name) NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX");
  db.command("CREATE INDEX "+className+".orgUnit ON "+className+" (orgUnit) NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX");
  db.command("CREATE INDEX "+className+".orgUnit_binName ON "+className+" (orgUnit,binName) NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX");
}
```

OrientDB javascript function which creates indexes for classes is stuck after following message.

> 2016-08-09 11:27:12:773 WARNI {db=Insight5} Page in file internal.pcl
>   with index 7 was placed in wrong free list, this error will be fixed
>   automatically. [OPaginatedCluster]2016-08-09 11:27:49

I am using:

**Windows 7 64 bit, java 8.0.31, 
orientdb-community-2.1.20, Xmx4096m, -Dstorage.diskCache.bufferSize=2048**

orientdb-server-config.xml:

```
<properties>
    <entry value="50" name="db.pool.min"/>
    <entry value="250" name="db.pool.max"/>
    <entry value="1000" name="script.pool.maxSize"/>        
    <entry value="false" name="profiler.enabled"/>
    <entry value="INFO" name="log.console.level"/>
    <entry value="INFO" name="log.file.level"/>
    <entry value="10000" name="storage.record.lockTimeout"/>
</properties>
```

thread dump:

```
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.31-b07 mixed mode):

"OrientDB HTTP Connection /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2480<-/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:52523" #32 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000021e5d800 nid=0x1a1c runnable [0x00000000230bf0
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
        - locked <0x00000006c3cdadf8> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.enterprise.channel.text.OChannelText.read(OChannelText.java:61)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.http.ONetworkProtocolHttpAbstract.execute(ONetworkProtocolHttpAbstract.java:571)
        at com.orientechnologies.common.thread.OSoftThread.run(OSoftThread.java:77)

"OrientDB HTTP Connection /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2480<-/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:52494" #23 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000022218800 nid=0x1cfc waiting on condition [0x00
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c05f14f0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$NonfairSync)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:870)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1199)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$WriteLock.lock(ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:943)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.cache.OCachePointer.acquireExclusiveLock(OCachePointer.java:199)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.cache.OCacheEntry.acquireExclusiveLock(OCacheEntry.java:79)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OPaginatedCluster.updateFreePagesList(OPaginatedCluster.java:1593)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OPaginatedCluster.updateFreePagesIndex(OPaginatedCluster.java:1549)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OPaginatedCluster.findFreePage(OPaginatedCluster.java:1482)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OPaginatedCluster.updateRecord(OPaginatedCluster.java:784)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.doUpdateRecord(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:1960)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.updateRecord(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:889)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.executeSaveRecord(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:2009)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionNoTx.saveRecord(OTransactionNoTx.java:160)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.save(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:2526)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.save(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:122)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument.save(ODocument.java:1759)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument.save(ODocument.java:1750)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexManagerAbstract$1.call(OIndexManagerAbstract.java:132)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OScenarioThreadLocal.executeAsDistributed(OScenarioThreadLocal.java:71)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexManagerAbstract.save(OIndexManagerAbstract.java:122)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexManagerShared.createIndex(OIndexManagerShared.java:167)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexManagerProxy.createIndex(OIndexManagerProxy.java:75)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OClassImpl.createIndex(OClassImpl.java:1759)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLCreateIndex.execute(OCommandExecutorSQLCreateIndex.java:264)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.execute(OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.java:90)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.executeCommand(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:1433)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.command(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:1406)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandRequestTextAbstract.execute(OCommandRequestTextAbstract.java:67)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.script.OScriptDocumentDatabaseWrapper.command(OScriptDocumentDatabaseWrapper.java:114)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.script.OScriptDocumentDatabaseWrapper.command(OScriptDocumentDatabaseWrapper.java:110)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/232925641.invokeVirtual_LL_L(LambdaForm$DMH)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$NamedFunction.invoke_LL_L(LambdaForm.java:1108)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/1971489295.invokeStatic_LL_L(LambdaForm$DMH)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$NamedFunction.invokeWithArguments(LambdaForm.java:1147)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm.interpretName(LambdaForm.java:625)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm.interpretWithArguments(LambdaForm.java:604)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$LFI/519569038.interpret_L(LambdaForm$LFI)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$NamedFunction.invoke_LL_L(LambdaForm.java:1108)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/1971489295.invokeStatic_LL_L(LambdaForm$DMH)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$NamedFunction.invokeWithArguments(LambdaForm.java:1147)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm.interpretName(LambdaForm.java:625)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm.interpretWithArguments(LambdaForm.java:604)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$LFI/519569038.interpret_L(LambdaForm$LFI)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH/1800412487.exactInvoker(LambdaForm$MH)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$BMH/1828757853.reinvoke(LambdaForm$BMH)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$NamedFunction.invoke_LLL_L(LambdaForm.java:1113)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/1971489295.invokeStatic_LL_L(LambdaForm$DMH)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$NamedFunction.invokeWithArguments(LambdaForm.java:1147)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm.interpretName(LambdaForm.java:625)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm.interpretWithArguments(LambdaForm.java:604)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$LFI/1844169442.interpret_L(LambdaForm$LFI)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/2114694065.invokeSpecial_LLLL_L(LambdaForm$DMH)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$NamedFunction.invoke_LLLL_L(LambdaForm.java:1118)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/1971489295.invokeStatic_LL_L(LambdaForm$DMH)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$NamedFunction.invokeWithArguments(LambdaForm.java:1147)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm.interpretName(LambdaForm.java:625)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm.interpretWithArguments(LambdaForm.java:604)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$LFI/1844169442.interpret_L(LambdaForm$LFI)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH/1786292209.linkToCallSite(LambdaForm$MH)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$\^eval\_$9.CD_CreateSubClassIndexes(<eval>:4628)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/1971489295.invokeStatic_LL_L(LambdaForm$DMH)
        at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH/1374677625.invokeExact_MT(LambdaForm$MH)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:535)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:209)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:378)
        at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror.callMember(ScriptObjectMirror.java:185)
        at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.invokeImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:505)
        at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.invokeFunction(NashornScriptEngine.java:227)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.script.OCommandExecutorFunction.executeInContext(OCommandExecutorFunction.java:94)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.function.OFunction.executeInContext(OFunction.java:149)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.http.command.all.OServerCommandAbstractLogic.execute(OServerCommandAbstractLogic.java:77)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.http.ONetworkProtocolHttpAbstract.service(ONetworkProtocolHttpAbstract.java:180)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.http.ONetworkProtocolHttpAbstract.execute(ONetworkProtocolHttpAbstract.java:627)
        at com.orientechnologies.common.thread.OSoftThread.run(OSoftThread.java:77)

"OrientDB Write Cache Flush Task (Insight5)" #22 daemon prio=10 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001e69b800 nid=0x233c runnable [0x0000000020fdf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c0a5c6d0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"OrientDB WAL Flush Task (Insight5)" #21 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001f512800 nid=0xd44 waiting on condition [0x0000000020e8e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c09edfc8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"DestroyJavaVM" #19 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000021ea000 nid=0x1eb4 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"OrientDB ONetworkProtocolHttpDb listen at 0.0.0.0:2480-2490" #16 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001e8bd800 nid=0x15b8 runnable [0x000000002080e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.accept0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:131)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:404)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:199)
        - locked <0x00000006c098b330> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.OServerNetworkListener.run(OServerNetworkListener.java:194)

"OrientDB ONetworkProtocolBinary listen at 0.0.0.0:2424-2430" #14 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001e8c3000 nid=0x16e8 runnable [0x00000000204de000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.accept0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:131)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:404)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:199)
        - locked <0x00000006c098cf40> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.OServerNetworkListener.run(OServerNetworkListener.java:194)

"Timer-0" #11 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001e792000 nid=0xd80 in Object.wait() [0x000000001ee3f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
        - locked <0x00000006c094a3e8> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

"Service Thread" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001d6a5000 nid=0x2108 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread2" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d63a800 nid=0x1bec waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d639000 nid=0x1c64 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d632800 nid=0x19ec waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Attach Listener" #5 daemon prio=5 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001c045800 nid=0x14cc runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001c044800 nid=0x2304 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=1 tid=0x000000001bfe8000 nid=0x1604 in Object.wait() [0x000000001d62f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:142)
        - locked <0x00000006c0861d78> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:158)
        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001bfdf000 nid=0x20c0 in Object.wait() [0x000000001d35f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
        at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:157)
        - locked <0x00000006c0b40cc8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"VM Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001bfdb000 nid=0x2078 runnable

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000021fe800 nid=0xbfc runnable

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002200000 nid=0x768 runnable

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002201800 nid=0x264 runnable

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002203000 nid=0x1d9c runnable

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d6a6800 nid=0x15e8 waiting on condition

JNI global references: 2513

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 928256K, used 76187K [0x000000076ab00000, 0x00000007bce00000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 924672K, 7% used [0x000000076ab00000,0x000000076f1f1ff0,0x00000007a3200000)
  from space 3584K, 98% used [0x00000007bbc00000,0x00000007bbf74dc0,0x00000007bbf80000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000007bc380000,0x00000007bc380000,0x00000007bce00000)
 ParOldGen       total 235008K, used 130502K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006ce580000, 0x000000076ab00000)
  object space 235008K, 55% used [0x00000006c0000000,0x00000006c7f71a28,0x00000006ce580000)
 Metaspace       used 30289K, capacity 31100K, committed 34304K, reserved 1081344K
  class space    used 3052K, capacity 3256K, committed 3328K, reserved 1048576K
```

Comment: How can I reproduce the problem? Could you post the code of your javascript function ?

Comment: @rota, I have updated the question with the executing function.

Comment: I not be able to reproduce the error, have you tried to do the export and import in the latest version of orient 2.2.6 and see if you have the same problem?

Comment: @rota as the db size is close to 6.5GB zipped Its not possible to upload it. Apologies.

Comment: Hi @ChamathKumarasinghe, I think Alessandro means that you need to export your db from 2.1.20, update orient server to 2.2.6 (last), and then import the db.